# Browser sends HTTP POST requests as GET requests

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a PHP Application which is written using CodeIgniter. I am facing a strange problem regarding HTTP requests. I noticed that the chrome developer tool shows the results of the HTTP request methods as `404 Not found` but I can receive the response from the application. Also another problem and my main problem is that the HTTP post requests are being sent as GET requests, however they are sent as GET methods. Here is the HTML form which sends the request:

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="login" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
    //                          
</form>
```

And if I debug the request by printing the value of `$_SERVER` variable I can see that the request method is `GET`:

```
'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => string 'HTTP/1.1' (length=8)
'REQUEST_METHOD' => string 'GET' (length=3)
'QUERY_STRING' => string '' (length=0)
```

And also there are these two more options that I don't know what they mean:

```
'REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD' => string 'POST' (length=4)
'REDIRECT_STATUS' => string '404' (length=3)
```

I am using Wamp on Windows 8.1 and CodeIgniter.

Comment: I think your script did a redirect to a page that does not exist... Because of the redirect to a non-existent page, the redirect will become a GET

Comment: `action="login"` there is no receiving  point in your form

Comment: @Raphioly-San The only reasoning would be that there is a redirect somewhere, but I checked and there is no redirect!

Comment: @Abdulla As you can see the action is `login` and it is relative to the current request, And also I can receive the request in the server side controller.

Comment: @mostafahakimi if login is name of your controller then you are wrong at all. Check answer below

Comment: The fact that you are seeing `REDIRECT_` vars at all suggests an _internal rewrite_ (aka _internal redirect_) is happening. (Probably due to the CodeIgniter front controller.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/login/function_name" method="post">
    <input  type="text" name="name"> 
    <input  type="email" name="email" > 
   <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" > //Important, this only submit the form 
</form
```

In `login` controller

```
public function function_name()
    {
        $name= $_POST['name']
        $email= $_POST['email']

        echo 'Name is :'.$name. 'and E-mail is : '.$email;
    }
```